# What's the easiest way to add an index on a live myISAM table?

Tags: sql, mysql, indexing, myisam

I have a myISAM table running in production on mySQL, and by doing a few tests, we've found we can tremendously speed up a query by adding a certain compound index. So far so good. However, I am not really about the best way to add this index in a production environment without locking the table for a long time (it's got 27GBs of data, so not so much, but it does take a while).

Do you have any tips? If this was a more sophisticated setup of course we'd have a live replica of all of the data on another machine, and we could safely switch. Unfortunately, we're not there yet, and I would like to speed up this query as soon as possible (it's causing big customer headaches). Is there some simple way to replicate the data and then do a swap-out trick? Some other tricks that I am missing?

UPDATE: Reading about "Online Index Operations" in SQL Server makes me very jealous http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191261.aspx :)

Thanks!

Comment: Can you restrict write-access to the database for a while?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use replication to get downtime on the order of a couple minutes, instead of the hours it might take to create an index on that table.

to set up the slave, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-howto-existingdata.html

a recommendation i can make to help speed up the process is in step 2 follow the "Creating a Data Snapshot Using Raw Data Files" method. but instead of copying over the wire to the slave, copy to a different location on the master. and bring the master back up as soon at the copy is done and you've made the necessary changes to the config file (set server-id and enabled binary logging). this will minimize your downtime to just a minute or two. once the server is back up, you can copy the copied files to the slave box.

once you have the slave up and running and you have [verified everything is replicating properly](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-administration-status.html), you can [pause the slave](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-administration-pausing.html). create the index on the salve. when the index creation is complete, resume the slave. this will catch the slave up to the master. on the master, use FLUSH TABLE WITH READ LOCK. check the slave status to make sure the log position on the master and the slave match. if they do, shut down the slave and copy the files for that table back to the master.

Answer (score 1):

I'm with Randy. We've been in a similar situation, and there are two ways in MySQL to accomplish something like this:

1. Take down the server while it runs. This is what you'll probably do. It's simple, it's easy, it works. Time to do? Maybe a half hour/45 minutes, dependent on disk bandwidth. See below.
2. Make a new table with the new index, copy all the data over, pause the server delete the first table, alter the new one to the old name, start the server. Downtime? 10 minutes, maybe, but really complicated.

Option two works, and saves you the downtime of creating the index (if it takes a long time). But it takes more space, it's more complicated (since you have to deal with the new records inserted off the main table, and it will probably lock on MyISAM while copying the data out. Deleting a table will take some time, altering the table to the new name will take some time. It's just really complicated. If you had a 2TB table this might be useful, but for 27G it's probably overkill.

Do you have a second server that is close in specifications to your production server? Load up your most recent backup and do the index there, so you know about how long it will take to add. Then plan for downtime.

InnoDB is better about many things, but new indexes still lock the table. Those abilities that MSSQL (and I think PostgreSQL) have to do those kind of things without locking would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Find your low usage window and take your application offline during the index build. Since you don't have replication or a multimaster or whatever, you're just going to have to bite the bullet on this one. See you at 1am. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not much you can do with one server here.

If you copy the table and do a dry run, at least you'll find out how long it's going to take without locking the live table, so you can schedule some maintenance time if necessary, or make a decision whether you can just push the button and leave users hanging for a couple of minutes :)

Or schedule it for a quiet time...

```
at 04:00 /usr/bin/mysql -uXXX -pXXX -e 'alter table mytable add key(col1, col2)'
```