# Adding Index to 3 million rows MySQL

Tags: mysql, indexing, innodb

I need to add at least 1 index to a column of type int(1) on an InnoDB table. There are about 3 million rows that it would need to index. This is a database on my production server, and it is in use by thousands of people everyday. I tried to add an index the standard way, but it was taking up too much time (I let it run for about 7 minutes before killing the process) and locking rows, meaning a frozen application for many users.

My VPS that runs all of this has 512mb of RAM and has an Intel Xeon E5504 processor.

How can I add an index to this production database without interrupting my user's experience?

Comment: Are the users writing/updating to the table all the time ? Can't you just add the column and launch indexing during the night ?

Comment: I think you can do it at 4am in the night...

Comment: This table is one of the focal points of a user's interaction. There is 2 transactions/second on average on this table, but at peak times can be as high as 10 transactions/second.

Comment: What is the cardinality of the column that you wish?  The display width of 1 suggests to me that it might be a boolean flag (with a cardinality of 2), which won't make for a very useful index.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add index to 18 GB innodb mysql table without affecting production performance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274630/how-to-add-index-to-18-gb-innodb-mysql-table-without-affecting-production-perfor)

Comment: It's a very expensive operation. Downtime is your best bet. DFo it on a copy of the table, get an idea of the no load cost, you might want to get an idea of the benefit of it as well, to avoid looking silly. Then armed with the figures, get some maintenance time planned in.

Comment: Well I also need an index on 2 other columns with types int(5) and int(11). Sorry for not mentioning it before, I just figured the int(1) would be the simplest case scenario to show off first.

Comment: @BertB. Be sure to add all the indexes at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the table either reads XOR writes then you'll probably need to take down the site. Lock the databases, run the operation and wait.

If the table is a write only swap the writes to a temporary table and run the operation on the old table, then swap the writes back to the old table and insert the data from the temporary table.

If the table is read only, duplicate the table and run the operation on the copy.

If the table is a read/write then a messy alternative that *might* work, is to create a new table with the indexes and set the primary key start point to the next value in the original table, add a join to your read requests to select from both tables, but write exclusively to the new table. Then write a script that inserts from the old table to the new then deletes the row in the old table. It'll take far, far longer than the downtime, and plenty can go wrong, but it should be do-able.

you can set the start point of a primary key with

```
ALTER TABLE `my_table` AUTO_INCREMENT = X;
```

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [pt-online-schema-change](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-online-schema-change.html). i think this tool can be quite useful in your case. it will obviously put additional load on your database server but should not block access to the table for most of the operation time.